# Checking if textbox corresponds with any of the strings of a text file.VB.NET VB2010

Tags: vb.net

I'm working to make a POS software in vb2010,but i'm stuck at this issue:
I'm trying to make the following: * means that it's what I want how the code to be:

```
   if textbox1.text = *matches to a barcode then
dim bar as string
dim price as string
dim name as string
bar = *get.currentline.ofbarcode()
price = readtextline(bar+1)
name = readtextline(bar+2)
namelist.items.add(name)
pricelist.items.add(price)
end if
```

NOTE: I'm not a begginer!I'm medium advanced
If it exists another post that's the same that I requested,you can write me with the topic and close this topic.I'm still learning...

Thank you!

EDIT:
The file form is like so(it's C:\price.ini):

```
      barcode1
    price1
    name1
    barcode2
    price2
    name2
at end,
9879,security label
```

and so on...

Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to load all the barcodes from the file in to an array or list, then you can loop through the array and see if any of the barcodes match the entered code

Answer (score 0):

If you have control of how the text file is created, you might find it easier to have one line (containing barcode, price and name) for each item, but the following code uses the format that you have posted.

You can use `System.IO.ReadAllLines` to read the entire text file into a String array. Then loop through the array checking every third element to see if it is the barcode you want. When you find what you want, add the next two elements to your ListBoxes.

```
Dim lines() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\price.ini")
For i As Integer = 0 To lines.Length - 1 Step 3
    If lines(i) = TextBox1.Text Then
        priceList.Add(lines(i + 1))
        nameList.Add(lines(i + 2))
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

If I run this code with the text file that you posted, I see that with "999" in TextBox1, I see "1" in priceList and "Soap" in nameList; and with "333" in TextBox1, I see "2" in priceList and "Bread" in nameList.

Comment: Thanks.I Will try IT.

Comment: I forgot again!
The price.ini structure it was like so!Sorry!
`barcode1
price1
name1
barcode2
price2
name2
9879
Security pass:9879`

Comment: Something is wrong!I scanned the barcode but what do I get is 1(to namelist) and 0(to pricelist).
I mean:
NameList and PriceList are listboxes!
The code detects the barcode,but it gives the above values(I edited a little bit the code to add to the listboxes).

Comment: @talnacialexandru_vb2010 If you want to make sure that last line in the file is ignored, change the For statement to `For i As Integer = 0 To Lines.Length - 2 Step 3`.

Comment: @talnacialexandru_vb2010 If the 0 in nameList and 1 in priceList are not the correct values, it would help if you post the contents of the text file and what your code looks like now that you have modified it.

Comment: I did posted a answer with the contents of the code and price.iniThank You for helping me until here!Please,someone wants it to be done in three months.I also need to make a custom pos system.

Comment: @talnacialexandru_vb2010 I see that I had name and price in the wrong order. I have updated the code in my answer and tested it with the text file that you posted.

Comment: @talnacialexandru_vb2010 Glad it's working. You might want to delete the answer you posted. It is not actually an answer to the question, but further information about the question. It is likely that someone will flag it for deletion, or perhaps downvote it.